# Переключение между окнами Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Есть Frame - первое окно

Есть Dialog - второе окно

После нажатия Button на Frame нужен плавный переход на Dialog.

Реализовал это вот так :

```
 dialog.show();
 this.hide();
```

Прикрепите документацию по Swing на русском (не просто перечисление всех методов или JavaDocs,если нет туториала) или подскажите как лучше сделать переход от одного окна к другому.

Comment: Что значит плавный переход? Диалог - это обычно модальное окно, то есть пока оно открыто, оно перекрывает другие окна.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman есть гайд по окнам или руководство?

Comment: да. руководство есть. я рекомендую использовать [официальное руководство](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman внизу в ответе написал,что требовалось. За руководство спасибо,я его видел)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor дело не во владении английским,дело в подаче информации,например в ответе,который я прикрепил ниже я дал ссылку на,так сказать,учебник по Swing и демонстрации его возможностей. Tutorial от Oracle показывает только методы,как они работают и не объясняют нюансов,которые нужно объяснять на русском языке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Люди любят минусовать темы последнее время, нет бы сказать, что

```
this.hide();
```

устарел и просто напиши:

```
dispose();
```

Всем, кто будет иметь проблемы вот в этом гайде всё подробно есть
"библиотека программиста иван портянкин swing-эффектные пользовательские интерфейсы"

Comment: минусуют потому-что вы задаете не понятные вопросы

Comment: @MikhailVaysman ну вот смотрите сами,я написал,что если использовать this.hide(); смена окон выглядит очень страшно,она не плавная,если использовать dispose(); смена окон окажется плавное,не квадратной. Как объяснить это иначе?

Comment: где вы это написали? В вопросе этого нет.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вы серьезно?

Comment: я вам даже специально задал уточняющий вопрос. На который вы не ответили.